# How to color object based on distance from camera with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to recreate this effect
[Is it possible to change an object's color depending on its distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72302/is-it-possible-to-change-an-objects-color-depending-on-its-distance#72475)
In my project, I have 2*2 KM plane which need to be painted gradually in different colors based on distance from camera.
I've tried this:
[Is it possible to calculate the distance between the vertices of two objects in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247657/is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-distance-between-the-vertices-of-two-objects-in?newreg=33e8a6cc09284440968a8de922bd744c)
but it didn't help me.
Thank you for response.

Comment: In which way it didn't help you? What _Geometry Nodes_ setup do you have so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

A camera has no geometry, so you would have to convert the instance of the camera into a point with `Instances to Points`.

You can then use this point as a reference with `Geometry Proximity` and thus assign values to the points of your mesh.

The values resulting from the distance to the camera you would have to adjust to your needs with `Map Range`.

You store these values with `Store Named Attribute` in the geometry, which you can read again in the shader with `Attribute` and convert into a color.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

---

**Update**

Of course you can solve this even easier (thanks to @Gordon Brinkmann for the attentive reading):

Instead of solving the distance via `Geometry Proximity`, you can directly do the distance to the camera with `Vector Math`:

[image]

Comment: No need for the _Store Named Attribute_, just plug the _Result_ from the _Map Range_ node into the empty socket of the _Group Output_ and give it the name in the modifier.

Comment: Oh, and you could calculate the distance between the camera's location and the position of the plane's vertices by using a _Vector Math_ node. No need for geometry proximity and hence no converting of the camera into a point. And you can leave the camera's _Object Info_ node at default values, no switching to _Relative_ or enabling _As Instance_.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you, that is completely correct! I have once again thought a little more complicated than necessary :D ...but with the example can still do a lot.

Comment: I actually thought the OP was asking for what the link directly showed me at first, cubes that get an overall uniform color depending on the distance instead of a gradient. In this case your _Store Named Attribute_ (or _Capture Attribute_ linked to the _Group Output_)  with domain set to _Instance_ would be the better solution, since you can capture the location of the instances. Coloring the cubes differently only works if you realize the instances, but then you'll get the gradient with my simpler solution. The _Store Named/Capture Attribute_ gets the location before they are realized.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: Looks like you are the only one here who reads ALL the answers :D (and understands them) :D :D

Comment: @Chris Well, not really all, only the ones where I'm curious for an answer myself or where I've got my own solution for. Like here, although my solution for the plane gradient works without _Attribute_ (_Store Named_ or _Capture_) node. I also have a solution for cubes with single colors per instance and a combination of having a gradient on a plane and colors per instance on the cubes in the same node tree. ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, I cant thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color-change at render-time and/or at render, (rather than the geometry's,) resolution, it might be better to do this with a shader?

[image]

You always have the option of baking the color to an image-texture..

[image]